# How can I use jQuery to remove more than one string from HTML?

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery to remove the first option group:

```
var topicSelectHtml = $('#TopicID')
    .clone()
    .find("optgroup:first")
    .remove().end().html();
```

From the following HTML:

```
<select name="TopicID" id="TopicID">
   <optgroup label="Admin">
      <option value="0000">All Topics</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="AA">
      <option value="05**">a</option>
      <option value="0505">b</option>
      <option value="0510">c</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="BB">
      <option value="10**">d</option>
      <option value="1005">e</option>
   </optgroup>
</select>
```

Is there a way I can also make it so the options that have a value ending in "**" are also removed?

Comment: You have to select all `option[value]`, then loop through all the elements and check/remove them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's [ends with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) selector:

```
var topicSelectHtml = $('#TopicID')
    .clone()
    .find("optgroup:first").remove().end()
    .find("option[value$='**']").remove().end().html();
```